# How can I convert image uri (not url) to base 64 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64, expo

I'm trying to create a mobile application with react native and expo for the machine learning classification image. My application take photos from the camera and send the PhotoUri to a function that return the prediction. How can I convert the image uri to base 64 string?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the official `expo-image-picker`. The package offer option to capture image via camera or load them from the media library

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'

  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      base64:true // Return base64 image data
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      //
    }
  }
```